# Assigning a single IP address in virt-manager

Tags: ubuntu, virt-manager

I'm using virt-manager in Ubuntu 16.04 is there anyway to assign the IP I bought to my VM? The guest operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

add network section in your machine's XML which should be probably in /etc/libvirt/qemu/yourmachine.xml